Does setting `PHPickerViewController.preferredAssetRepresentationMode` to `.current` really work?
Doc says I can set preferredAssetRepresentationMode to .current to avoid transcoding.
var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current

Problem is, PHPickerViewController always opens a picker with a "Options" button at bottom:

when you tap "Options", you can see the default asset representation mode is still "Default", not "Current".

So does setting PHPickerViewController.preferredAssetRepresentationMode to .current really work?
